# Hiding keyboard before activity is visible

Tags: android, android-activity, keyboard

I have an activity (A) which launches activity (B).

Activity A using keyboard in some situations.

I want to hide the keyboard (if it is showed) before B is launched.

However,when A launches B, the keyboard is still
visible for a just seconds after B is already visible.

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
startActivity(..); //starts Activity B
```

How can I hide the keyboard before B is called? thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the onResume() of Activity B hide the keyboard

```
public void onResume()
{
  super.onResume();
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
}
```

In the onPause() of Activity A hide the keyboard

```
public void onPause()
    {
      super.onPause();
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    }
```

Comment: not working. I still see the keyboard for a second after the activity (B) is visible

Comment: sorry but doesn't work. i still see the keyboard after B is visible.

Comment: InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
//    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(message.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0); This is also for hide the Keyboard

Comment: calling getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN); in onPause() when keyboard is hidden results in opening it in the previous activity.

Comment: implementing this in onResume() did the job

Answer (score 2):

add in your `AndroidManifest.xml` for you activity
`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"`
to be like this

```
  <activity
      android:name="com.me.MyActivity"
      android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
   />
```